# VB.net retrieve specific value from an array create by a class?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I have a Class called 'account'. Here is the code:

```
 Public Class Account
Private accounttype As String
Private accountnumber As Integer
Private branchcode As String
Private currency As String
Private balance As Integer

Public Sub New()
    accounttype = " "
    accountnumber = 0
    branchcode = " "
    currency = " "
    balance = 0
End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal cu As String, ByVal na As Integer, ByVal su As String, ByVal a1 As String, ByVal a2 As Integer)
    accounttype = cu
    accountnumber = na
    branchcode = su
    currency = a1
    balance = a2
End Sub
Public ReadOnly Property Getaccountnumber() As String
    Get
        Return accountnumber
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Getbalance() As Integer
    Get
        Return balance
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return "Account Type: " & accounttype & vbCrLf & "Account Number: " & accountnumber.ToString & vbCrLf & "Branch Code: " & branchcode & vbCrLf & "Currency: " & currency & vbCrLf & "Balance: " & balance.ToString

End Function


End Class
```

I have then hard coded a few accounts like this.

```
    Dim account1 As New Account("Savings", "1", "S1", "Khajalee", 1000)
    accodetails.Add(account1)
```

I would like to know how I go about getting the 'balance' value for an account from the array. Any help would be wonderful!!As you can see i have tried getting the balance with a few different codes but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided, by "the array", you mean `accodetails`, then you can access any item in the array by index, like this:

```
Dim myAccount As Account = accodetails(0)
```

Then you can access any property in the `Account` object via that variable, like this:

```
Dim myBalance As Integer = myAccount.GetBalance
```

Or, more simply, you can access the property directly from the item in the list, without assigning it to a variable, like this:

```
Dim myBalance As Integer = accodetails(0).GetBalance
```

Comment: Quick question, how would I go about permanently changing that value after adding funds to the balance? thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The class, as you've shown it, doesn't allow changes to its balance.